# how to add UILabel and UIText on the background image

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

This is part of my code.
I want to show two `UILabel` and two `UITextField` on the background image: `backgroundLogin.jpg`   .

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
class LoginViewController:UIViewController
{
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let BackGroundImage:UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width , self.view.frame.height))

    let image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "backgroundLogin.jpg")!

    BackGroundImage.image = image
    self.view.addSubview(BackGroundImage)
    //self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "backgroundLogin.jpg")!)

    username.text = "User name"
    password.text = "Password"

}

@IBOutlet weak var username: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var password: UILabel!

}
```

**But when this code runs, it looks like:**

[image]

I hope it can have two label on the image, but how to add that ?

Comment: your background image may be stacking on top of the labels and text. Have you tried adding the UIImageView in storyboard first?

Comment: Have you tried self.view.bringSubviewToFront(YOUR_UILABEL)

Comment: I haven't tried. I am very new to swift and IOS development, there are a lot of functions I don't know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well like I stated in the comment you should try bring the UILabels to the front.

Since you are doing this programatically it can be done with `bringSubviewToFront` here is Apple's documentation on this and other UIView functionality you can use. Note: UILabel inherits from UIView so you can use these methods.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW46

The code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let BackGroundImage:UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width , self.view.frame.height))

    let image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "backgroundLogin.jpg")!

    BackGroundImage.image = image
    self.view.addSubview(BackGroundImage)
    //self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "backgroundLogin.jpg")!)

    username.text = "User name"
    password.text = "Password"

    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(username)
    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(password)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are adding the UIImageView in code and the UILabels on storyboard, then when you run the app the labels are behind the UIImageView and you can't see then.

Just check it adding `BackGroundImage.hidden = true` in viewDidLoad.

You can't add UILabels into a UIImageView. One solution would be add all views in code, 1st the image view and then the labels over it. Other option would be add all then in storyboard in the same order.

Like this:[image]

Answer (score 0):

You’re doing a lot here programmatically that you don’t need to do.

1. In Storyboard, add a UIImageView to a blank ViewController (you
   can rename the view controller later if you wish)
2. With the new UIImageView selected, control-drag to create an outlet in your view controller named backgroundImage
3. With the UIImageView selected, choose the image you want it to display by going to the Attribute Inspector and from the dropdown
   box, select your image. All images in your project should appear in
   the dropdown box.
4. Now add a UILabel to the ViewController and control-drag to create an outlet in the corresponding code
5. In the viewDidLoad() method, bring the outlet to the front

All this requires code-wise is:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var backgroundImage: UIImageView!
  @IBOutlet weak var username: UILabel!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(username)
  }
}
```